# Resizing grid of rectangles in SwiftUI when window resizes using GeometryReader

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm writing a SwiftUI view to act as a viewport into an infinite grid of cells. I want the number of rows and columns shown in the view to depend on the size of the window (this is a mac app).

When I write it with hardcoded number of rows and columns (e.g., `ForEach(0..<10)`) it works perfectly. But when I switch to calculating the number of rows and columns using `GeometryReader`, the Rectangles disappear.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let cellSize: CGFloat = 40
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<Int(geometry.size.height / self.cellSize)) { _ in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<Int(geometry.size.width / self.cellSize)) { _ in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. This is a screenshot, please confirm if what I am seeing is correct. https://ibb.co/7QtpZBs I am running `macOS Catalina 10.15.4` and `iPhone 11 pro (13.4.1)` and `xcode: 11.4.1`

Comment: @MuhandJumah I'm writing a macOS app not iPhone, but I think the problem I'm facing might show up on the iPhone if you rotate it, it should switch to a grid with same size cells but with more cells horizontally than vertically but I don't think it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is in constant `ForEach` (ie. range-based constructor) . If number of views is going to be changed we should use dynamic `ForEach`. Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.5.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(repeating: 0, count: 
                    Int(geometry.size.height / self.cellSize)), id: \.self) { _ in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(Array(repeating: 0, count: 
                            Int(geometry.size.width / self.cellSize)), id: \.self) { _ in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I also had to conform `Int` to `Identifiable`. One problem though is I can't index the cells now since they're all `Int`'s with a value of `0` so what I did instead is used the range from my original code but just added the `id: \.self` argument to `ForEach`. Specifically, the issue was that there's an overload of `ForEach` that takes a range but expects the range to stay the same over time, likely for performance reasons.